# Can Nginx translate TLS 1.0 to 1.3 for clients incompatible with TLS 1.3?

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have old appliances that either do not support TLS or only support TLS 1.0.

Can Nginx translate between these incompatible devices using only HTTP or TLS 1.0 and endpoints that use TLS 1.3?

Comment: Not exactly translate, but yes your nginx can take browser/client side TLS 1.0 connections and forward requests to upstream in TLS 1.3. But retiring such old stuffs is still recommended.

Comment: I was meaning the other way.  things like old apc pdu's from the 90's cant talk tls3 and would need nginx to do something allow the browser to recieve tls3.

Comment: is this Stall equipment still in use for a production business environment? can you please confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short and Dirty Answer:

Yes, you can, but you should retire such old equipment. Nginx doesn't care what's beyond it, even if it is a valid or invalid SSL certificate in the Default Configuration.

### Sample Configuration:

```
server {
        server_name tld.domain.it;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/tld.domain.it.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/tld.domain.it.error.log;
        listen [::]:443 ssl ;
        listen 443 SSL ;
        #Useful for the old site
        proxy_no_cache 1;
        proxy_cache_bypass 1;
        
        #For reaaaly old broken stuff, force IE-Emulation Mode (may help)
        #add_header ‘X-UA-Compatible’ ‘IE=EmulateIE7’;
        
        #Force tls1
        #proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1

        # I prefer to log also rewrite
        rewrite_log on;
        proxy_pass                              https://127.0.0.1:12345;
        proxy_set_header                        Host $http_host;

    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/exmaple.it/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.it/privkey.pem; 


}
```

#### References

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html

Comment: `Nginx doesn't care what's beyond it` as long as it is compiled with the outdated ciphers.   This will change in future releases of nginx.

Comment: I agree that it _may_ change, but in the current point of development it is set by default to ignore ssl errors ;)